# How to prove that $f$ is injective if $\exists h \in H: |f^{-1}(\{h\})| = 1$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G,H$ be groups and $f: G \to H$ a group homomorphism. I want to show that the following statements are equivalent:

1. $f$ is injective.
2. $\ker f = \{e_G\}$.
3. $\exists h \in H: |f^{-1}(\{h\})|=1$.

The standard solution suggests to show the equivalence of 1 and 2, and then the equivalence of 2 and 3 by proving both directions in each case. Therefore, it proves four implications. When I started to prove this, I tried to show only three implications, namely $1 \implies 2 \implies 3 \implies 1$. The first two implications were pretty easy, however I am stuck with the last implication.

Can anyone give me a hint?

Comment: Hint: Assume that $f$ is not injective, so you have two element $g_1$ and $g_2$ both sent to the same $k\in H$. Try to construct from these two new elements $g_1'$ and $g_2'$ which are both sent to the given $h$. Do this in a way that allows to to recover that $g_1=g_2$ from $g_1' = g_2'$.

Comment: What is wrong with going via (2)?

Comment: If you go $1 \Longrightarrow 3 \Longrightarrow 2 \Longrightarrow 1$, you get an easier (more directly obvious) proof, IMO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**: Let $g_1, g_2 \in G$ with $f(g_1) = f(g_2)$. Let $h$ as in 3 and $f^{-1}(\{h\}) = \{g\}$. Then $f(gg_1g_2^{-1}) = h$, so $gg_1g_2^{-1} = g$.

Comment: As simple, short as that. +1

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Show that $|f^{-1}({h})|$ is the same size for any $h$ in the image of $f$.

Answer (score 0):

Now $f(g) = f(g')$ if and only if $g \operatorname{Ker}(f) = g' \operatorname{Ker}(f)$, which gives $(1) \Leftrightarrow (2)$.

If $f(g) = h$, then $f^{-1}(\{h\}) = g \operatorname{Ker}(f)$. With this, $(2) \Leftrightarrow (3)$ is immediate.